# When creating Associated Token Account "Provided owner is not allowed"

Tags: spl-token, web3.js, associated-token-account

I am trying to create associated token accounts for SPL Transfers and I keep running into Provided Owner not allowed. I have never seen this error before and I am checking to make sure the token account is oncurve.
Here is a sample transaction https://solscan.io/tx/272uxvnGqYUb9Ri8E7y5u5153oSCAvjrT1quE298kLS8tmhMp5Q9SNfYgrx1Lcv9L6bif4nUeKBRFRSeFPo75Ec9
The code to create the associated tokenaccount:

```
splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      keypair,
      mintPk,
      toWalletPk,
      false,
      'finalized',
      { skipPreflight: true, maxRetries: 100 },
      splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ),
  );
```

Transaction log output:

```
> Program log: Create
> Program Associated Token Account Program  consumed 3709 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: Provided owner is not allowed
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Seems like a new error.

Comment: Can you confirm that `toWalletPk` is a `PublicKey` and not a `KeyPair`

Comment: Yep, this is the toWalletPk: 
`const toWalletPk = new web3Js.PublicKey(toWallet);`

Comment: how are you getting the ```toWallet```?

Comment: Just a string of addresses i'm looping through, basically this just an NFT airdrop so its a list of holders of NFTs

Comment: ahh, are you sure that `toWallet` isn't an ATA already? Are you able to share an example public key?

Comment: @C.OG no it shouldn't be but I can add some code to double check. That was my suspicion as well but with the sample keys above they are both wallets. Not exactly sure still but everything ended up transferring ok, I was just curious how it would be possible. Before sending the SPL token I do call getOrCreatedAssociatedTokenAccount (from SPL library)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's ATA `2BYpRXiHUkr83cZaj1acT4xcNwVC9xW4vr9NbWmG2DMm` is closed by this transaction `53KbVo5VjtMd67pe9Wh9KsQiQowYLkKHsDfQKncPBCkA35KeFYYJ4tB2fCQ3nYEywH6zCpLLwHjHKoouchJmCv9o`.

Comment: Don't see how this factors in here since this transaction is from today rather than what happened 18 days ago. Appreciate the answer tho.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have `allowOwnerOffCurve` set to false. It should be set to `true` when you're creating an ATA whose owner is based on a PDA. I'm not sure if that's the case for the account in question, but the error you're getting is the same.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5d16d5b926cd677d40c3f207906085dd8f1a6aa5/token/js/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L22